# How to wait until thread is finished

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to implement the task below (my current method is quite naive and is causing me issues)

Here is the run down on what should happen when my app is started:

1. First the user is prompted to login to facebook.  I use facebooks
   DialogListener to listen for when it completes.
2. On completion of above task I use an AsyncFacebookRunner to collect some
   information about the user.  I use the
   AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener() to listen for when this
   completes.
3. On completion of task 2 I store some information in SharedPreferences

This all works splendidly.  Here is the issue... I need to use some of said information in a http POST to get data on the server.  The data is used to populate a gridview.  For this I am using a Asynctask.  My problem lies in not knowing when the data is there in SharedPreferences.

As of right now in the doInBackground I have a loop like this:

```
while (true)
{
    if (not a valid value of something in SharedPreferences)
         Thread.sleep(500);
    else
         break
}
```

Which is incredibly ugly, naive, and is giving me some issues.  At this point I feel like I should rewrite the whole thing so hopefully somebody can suggest a better method!

Comment: Is there a reason onPostExecute() method of the asynctask isn't suitable?  That's always executed after doInBackground, so if you get your preferences in doInBackground, then it will be available in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangedListener` with the `SharedPreferences` to be notified of when data changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your order of events correctly.  When #3 is running and saving the preferences, why can't it notify anything waiting on the values it is writing to SharedPreferences?  Event style.  That will eliminate the spin wait you're currently using.

Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: Well, as a new android developer (maybe there is something out there that I don't know about) I can't see a way to do that without some loop like I have above :/ I can't exactly call the Asynctask from the 2nd onComplete(where I write to sharedpreferences).  Maybe I miss what you are saying though :D

Comment: @IamAlexAlright: Why can't you call the Asynctask from there?

Comment: Why can't you call .execute on your asynctask after you right the shared preferences?

Comment: Because it was private... whoops >.<

Answer (score 0):

There various ways to perform this. You can use blocking queue to do this. So when there is valid SharedPreferences i.e. in the queue it will be consumed by the thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
private volatile boolean mLock = false;

void otherThreadFunc() {
    mLock = true;
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    mLock = false;
}

void mainThread() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            otherThreadFund();
        }
    }.start();

    // Wait...
    while(mLock) {
    }
}
```